# "$" is undefined; jquery clearly linked to in <head>; no conflicting scripts or libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, firebug

-=- THIS CODE FUNCTIONS. I AM LEFT TO ASSUME THERE WAS A PROBLEM WITH THE CACHE AS NOTHING HAS BEEN ALTERED BETWEEN NON-FUNCTION/FUNCTION. THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP (especially Niko who got the ball rolling and helped me form a richer understanding of jquery syntax) -=-

I've written this script by hand, and finally decided to update it to jquery in a bid to get used to that, and streamline the code.  This is supposed to render a simple menu (which it did before).

- Both .js files are in the same directory as the .html file.  This is being tested on my pc, not on a server.
- A previous version of this code worked perfectly just linking to taskMaster.js.  At that point my code didn't use "$" tagged calls.
- Firebug is displaying an error of "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when it tries to call `$(document).ready(function () {`
- the "net" tab doesn't display either .js files as being loaded; the net tab is completely empty and shows no activity - I believe this is because I'm testing this off my PC; the net panel is empty when I load the functioning code
- I've reinstalled a fresh version of jquery on the offchance there was something wrong, to no avail

Broken code "taskMaster.js":

```
$(document).ready(function () {


//main menu
function Main()
{
    var mainList = ["New List","Show Lists","Delete Lists"];
    //var onClick = [New,Lists,Delete];
    var mainMenu = new Menu("Main Menu","menuMain",mainList/*,null*/);
    mainMenu.contentMenu();
}
$(Main);


//menu class
function Menu(name,divClass,content/*,onclick*/)
{
    $("#interface").html(null);

    //title
    formatDiv("interface",name,divClass,name/*,null*/);

    //return
    if(name != "Main Menu")
    {
        formatDiv(name,null,"return","^ Main Menu","Main()");
    }


    //display options
    this.contentMenu = function()
    {
        for(i=0; i<content.length; i++)
        {
            formatDiv("interface",content+i,"menuContent",content[i]/*,onclick[i]*/);
        }
    }
}


//format divs
function formatDiv(target,divId,divClass,content/*,onclick*/)
{
    $("#"+target).append("<div id=\'" + divId + "\' class=\'" + divClass + "\'>" + content +"</div>");
    /*$("#"+divId).click(function()
    {
        onclick;
    });*/
}

});
```

I commented out unused lines, but it's showing "$" as undefined

Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="taskMaster.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="taskMaster.css" />
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="interface">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with this html - the same format worked perfectly fine before.  All that's changed is that I've introduced jquery and changed some commands in taskMaster.js to use "$".

Comment: Where and how is "Main()" called? You will need to make sure that this does not happen before the DOM is ready to be manipulated: Use `$(Main);` instead of a plain `Main();`. - Also, is there any output (errors) in the javascript console?

Comment: `Main()` is called in the <body> tag with onload. Where should I be looking for the javascript console?  I'm writing this in SciTE, so the only debugger I have is firebug. When you suggest `$(Main)`, should I be using the whole $(document).ready(); function to encapsulate all my jquery calls?

Comment: The firebug console is just fine. If there is any red output, something went wrong. And yes, you can also encapsulate the whole code in a ready-event handler: `$(document).ready(function() { /* your code */ });`

Comment: The console is completely empty.  When you say `/*my code*/`, do you mean the entire script?  Outside of checking DOM readiness, am I calling jquery correctly with things like: `$("#"+divId).click(onclick);`, or should that look like: `$("#"+divId).click(function(){onclick});` ???

Comment: The firebug net tab is disabled when you are just accessing `file:///` URLs.  The Chrome console shows them - what does it say?

Comment: I haven't been using chrome; I'm only developing this for personal use.  I'm teaching myself JS as a way of getting familiar with programming, and this was the project I came up with for myself. Regardless, I appreciate your attempt to help - but here's the thing.  It works now. I have no clue why. It's insane. I changed nothing; I reloaded it just after reading your suggestion and it's working. I'm flabbergasted BUT also pleased. Thank you everyone for your help, I may never know what was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'm now posting this as an answer, because it is easier to provide some examples here.

First thing is: Whenever you do an operation that accesses the DOM, such as `$("#interface").html(null);`, you will first need to make sure that the DOM is ready. This is what the "ready" event is for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* The code here is executed when the DOM is ready! */
});
```

So if "Main()" is a function that kicks everything off, you can simply list it to be called when the DOM is ready:

```
function Main() {
    /* ... */
}

$(document).ready(Main);
```

Most the time it is also safe to encapsulate the entire JavaScript code in a "ready" event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function Main() { /* ... */ }
    function formatDiv(...) { }
    // ...

    // All functions are defined, now let's go:
    Main();
});
```

---

Now the click handlers: jQuery's "click()" function expects a function that is to be called when the corresponding DOM elements gets clicked on. You're currently passing strings like "New()" to it, but you should directly pass the functions. To do so, alter the code in "Main()" this way:

```
// Old: var onClick = ["New()","Lists()","Delete()"];
var onClick = [New, Lists, Delete]; // New
```

This adds the actual functions to the array, not just their names.

Comment: This is great, it clarifies a lot of things; I'm going to edit my current code into question.  Now I'm finally getting errors in the console, and they're telling me that "$" is not defined.  I really appreciate your help by the way.

Comment: Did you define something like this in your index.html file (or other appropriate place?  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: just added the html to the question

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect the current situation.  I need to sleep soon - I really appreciate the help so far, hopefully this will be clearer when I wake up

Comment: The DOM doesn't necessarily need to be ready before you modify it - you can do things to an element as soon as it has been added.

Comment: @user1542645 That was just a comment on the answer.  I put a comment on your question - what does Chrome console say in its network tab?  It will show information even if you are looking at a local machine.

Comment: problem fixed itself with 0 changes to code.  I'm left to assume the cache was interfering in some way - the code blocks posted in the question work!